# Unable to strip off content disposition and other http headers from HTTP Get Response

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I am consuming a third party api where in i am fetching the file contents via HTTP GET, content-type is multipart/form-data.

When i try to save the response apart from the file contents, i see below information which i don't need, is there an easy way to exclude this information?

```bash
--63bc29ef89bca3f8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bytes_read"
Content-Type: text/plain

1048576
--63bc29ef89bca3f8
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="ee41de82-c8fe-42bd-a059-6197b16c6b21"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

**** file contents***
..

...



--63bc29ef89bca3f8

**** file contents***
..

...
```

Comment: To extract just the file contents and ignore the other parts like headers and metadata, you'll need to parse the multipart response.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("apiurl");

    if (response.Content is MultipartContent multipart)
    {
        await foreach (var content in multipart.ReadAsAsyncEnumerable())
        {
            if (content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName != null && content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet)
            {
                var fileContent = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                // Save fileContent to a file or use it as needed
            }
        }
    }
```

this is basic procedure we read fileContent please provide your code so that we can answer exactly and i hope this helps you out.

Comment: Probably better write `content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType ==  MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet`. It also prevents typing errors

Comment: @jimi I note that thanks.

Comment: @Suryateja KONDLA - I tried as you described above but the response is of type HttpConnectionResponseContent so this was not working

Comment: @Saravanan R Please change your question by pasting your example code snippet so that i will be helpful for us to modify.

Comment: @Suryateja KONDLA - I don't have enough reputation to edit the question with code snippet. I used the exact code you shared and in debug mode the below condition is not met                                ```if (response.Content is MultipartContent multipart)```

Comment: fyi without any code or specific issues in the question, there is no need to post any answer (Stack Overflow is not a place to post requirements and have others write code)